NextJS web scrapper is getting duplicate results Amazon product listing
I'm following a tutorial @1:27:20 this
Whenever I'm retrieve the Amazon Product price I get [currentPrice: '1799.1781.1799.'] it should be [1799]
import axios from "axios";
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';
import { extractPrice } from "../utils";

export async function scarpeAmazonProduct(url: string) {

    // BrightData proxy config
    const username = String(process.env.BRIGHT_DATA_USERNAME)
    const password = String(process.env.PASSWORD)
    const port = 22225;
    const session_id = (1000000 * Math.random()) | 0;
    const options = {
        auth: {
            username: `${username}-session-${session_id}`,
            password,
        },
        host: 'brd.superproxy.io',
        port,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }

    try {
        // Fetch the product page
        const response = await axios.get(url, options);
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        
        // Extract Product title
        const title = $('#productTitle').text().trim();
        
        const currentPrice = extractPrice(
            $('.priceToPay span.a-price-whole'),
            $('.a.size.base.a-color-price'),
            $('.a-button-selected .a-color-base'),
            $('span.a-price.a-text-price'),
        );

        console.log({ title, currentPrice });
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to scrape product: ${error.message}`)
    }
}

export function extractPrice(...elements: any) {
    for (const element of elements) {
        const priceText = element.text().trim();

        if (priceText) return priceText.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    }

    return '';
}

I've tried various selector tags only as to not stray too far from tutorial.
